# Custom UISlider inner bar corner radius issue iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, uislider, rounded-corners, cornerradius

in my custom UISlider I want to achieve a rounded corner inner bar. I'm using no thumb. it works fine in iOS 13, but in 14 it crashes with error :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Custom UISlider code

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider {
    
@IBInspectable var trackHeight: CGFloat = 30
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.sublayers![1].cornerRadius = 12
        self.thumbTintColor = .clear
    }
}
```

self.layer.sublayers![1].cornerRadius = 12, this line is creating the issue. If I comment this line code works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if let`...

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if let arrSubLayer = layer.sublayers, arrSubLayer.count > 1 {
      arrSubLayer[1].cornerRadius = 12
    }
    self.thumbTintColor = .clear
}
```

It will check for the sub layers. If any then it will check the count > 1 as you are trying to trying to access index 1.

Comment: it doesn't cause the crash but still the inner part is not rounded with corner radius. But same code works fine in older Xcode version.